# Wrapping my head around "snap to" guideline(s)

Tags: c#, wpf

So I created this window editor in WPF that helps me create Forms quickly. Now, one feature I've worked on was create a guideline tool. At its core it's just creates lines to help keep my UI elements organized on the screen. I will show you an example. The long black lines are the guidelines I spoke about earlier.

[image]

Now, I noticed that in a lot of art programs (i.e Photoshop) and popular IDEs that implement Forms that they have a "snap-to" feature where a UI element will snap to a line UI or to another UI element in order to maintain alignment. Something like this:

[image]

I already have the guidelines showing up in my editor. Now, what I would like help understanding is, how would I go about implementing the "snap to" feature? I'n not asking for code, just a breakdown (a visual breakdown will be most welcomed).

These are my questions:

1. How does an object know if one of its edges (top, bottom, left, right) touched a line?
2. How would I know how to unsnap the UI element if the user keeps moving the mouse past the guideline?
3. If I have (say) 10 lines how do I make sure that the object attaches to the nearest line(s)?

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: When an object moves or is resized, keep track of its actual size/location relative to the mouse, and separately keep track of a snapped version of the same information. If a given actual edge is within some arbitrary distance of a line -- say 4 pixels (arbitrary WPF units, really). If it's within that distance, set it to the value for the line it's close to. You still have the *actual* mouse-relative values as well, so you know to unsnap it if the the user keeps on dragging it and it leaves that 4-unit zone. Locating the snap lines is easy -- `%` again.

Comment: When user drags object and object's edge is close to the line (like 10 pixels, or less or 20 pixels etc ) - snap it to line (that is - immediately move to the line. When user drags snapped object - don't move it until the same distance is reached, then immediately move it out to that distance (unsnap).

Comment: @ Ed Plunkett YYour logic is sound! I implemented it and it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an object moves or is resized, keep track of its actual size/location relative to the mouse, and separately keep track of a snapped version of the same information. If a given actual edge is within some arbitrary distance of a line -- say 4 pixels (arbitrary WPF units, really). If it's within that distance, set it to the value for the line it's close to. You still have the actual mouse-relative values as well, so you know to unsnap it if the the user keeps on dragging it and it leaves that 4-unit zone.

When an object is being resized, at most two edges of the bounding box will be changing position (assuming you can drag corners as well as edges). When you're moving an object, all four edges of the bounding box will move.

So you need to keep track of which edges are moving, and only do snap-line proximity testing on those edges. When you're moving an object, snapping the left or top edge to a line is easy. That's just the position of the object. But if you snap the right or top edge to a line, you're setting

```
snappedPos.X = nearestVerticalSnapLine.X - draggedObject.Width;
```

or

```
snappedPos.Y = nearestHorizontalSnapLine.Y - draggedObject.Height;
```

You may also have cases where opposite edges will both be in proximity to lines: Say you're dragging a seven-unit square across a ten-unit grid. When it's inside a grid box, all four sides will be in proximity to a grid line. Which wins? The closer one.

Locating the snap lines is easy -- `%`.

Comment: one last thing: how do I test if the UI object is touching the top or bottom horizontal line? And thanks again for the first answer. That helped a lot!

Comment: Glad to help. What do you mean, "the top or bottom horizontal line"? Do you mean whether the bottom of the object is touching the line below, or the top is touching the line above?

Comment: correct, say my object's bottom is touching the top line, I want to then anchor it to the bottom. I wish I could attach an image

Comment: Plenty of room for more images in your question.

Comment: I added the image

Comment: so far so goo. Now, how would I check if (say) I wanted to check if the box is within range of the top side line then snap it to the bottom?

Comment: @user3838697 Show me a picture. What edge is in range of what line?

Comment: look at the same image I uploaded earlier. Let's use the UI Object 1 as an example. How do I check for that?

Comment: How do you check for what? Are you asking me to write the code?